# How to ensure that the JSON string is UTF-8 encoded in Java

Tags: java, json, encoding, utf-8

I am working on a legacy web service client code where the JSON data is being sent to the web service. Recently it was found that for some requests in the JSON body, the service is giving HTTP 400 response due to invalid characters (non-UTF8) in the JSON Body.

Below is one example of the data which is causing the issue.

```
String value = "zu3z5eq tô‰U\f‹Á‹€z";
```

I am using `org.json.JSONObject.toString()` method to generate the JSON string. Can you please let me know how can I ensure that the JSON string is UTF-8 encoded?

I already tried few solutions like available online , like converting to byte array and then back, using java charset methods etc, but they did not work. Either they convert the valid values as well like chinese/japanese characters, or doesn't work at all.

Can you please provide some input on this?

Comment: What JSON library are you using? How are you sending the request to the server?

Comment: org.json.JSONObject

Comment: How is `String value` actually being assigned?  "zu3z5eq tô‰U\f‹Á‹€z"` is not JSON, so I assume it didn’t come from JSONObject.toString.

Comment: This is just a sample data which is part of the json. Not the actual json

Comment: The data is being entered from the front end application.

Comment: OK so you're using `JSONObject.toString()` to generate the string - how do you send this string to the server? That's most likely where the encoding is wrong.

Comment: This is how I am sending the string.            httpConn.connect();
                wr = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(jsonObject.toString());

                wr.flush();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the character encoding for `OutputStreamWriter` when you create it:

```
 httpConn.connect();
 wr = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
 wr.write(jsonObject.toString());
 wr.flush();
```

Otherwise it defaults to the "platform default encoding," which is some encoding that has been used historically for text files on whatever system you are running.

Comment: Hi, I tried this, however it still did not for some reason. Below is the JSON which I sent {

 
    "DESCRIPTION": "zu3z5eq tô‰U\f‹Á‹\u0017€z"
} and the error received was 400 along with: The body of the request, which was expected to be JSON, was invalid, and could not be decoded. The string syntax was invalid.

Comment: This is valid JSON syntax and the character encoding is correct. It sounds like you'll have to contact whoever is providing this API to you, it may be a bug on their end. Perhaps they have extra requirements that are not in the JSON standard, like not allowing the escape code `\f`.

Answer (score -1):

Use Base64 encoding for converting the value to Byte[].

```
  String value = "zu3z5eq tô‰U\f‹Á‹€z";

    // WHILE  SENDING  ENCODE THE VALUE
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    String encodedValue = new String(encodedBytes, "UTF-8");

    // TRANSPORT....

    // ON RECEIVING END DECODE THE  VALUE
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedValue.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println( new  String(decodedBytes, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: I do not have control on the receiving service. So this will not work for me.